# getting invalid syntax error in python 3.8

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make my first Django application, but I keep seeing "invalid syntax" error at the second url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index')
    url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.details, name ='details')
];
```

why does this occur?

Comment: Please give some more details about what you have done and give a brief detail about your project as well so that others can get a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlpatterns` is a `list`, and `list` values need to be comma separated.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.details, name ='details')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

since `urlpatterns` was a `list`, you need "," to separate each item, the correct code of yours is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details, name ='details')
];
```

Please mention the ',' if you want to create a `list`

Answer (score 0):

Django urlpatterns is a list in list you want to separate with `,` so you need to add `,` after every item

I Simply Code For You Try This:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.details, name ='details'),
];
```